# PDO insert successful but not?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to insert into a MySQL table with PDO.
Code:

```
public function sendMail($to, $body) {
    /* this all works
     *
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    $stmt = $this->database->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
    $stmt->execute();
    $fetch = $stmt->fetchAll();
    print_r($fetch);
     */

    $stmt = $this->database->prepare("INSERT INTO 
        inbox_unread (date, body, to, from) VALUES (:date, :body, :to, :from)");
    echo $stmt->bindParam(":date", date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
    echo $stmt->bindParam(":body", $body);
    echo $stmt->bindParam(":to", $to);
    echo $stmt->bindParam(":from", $_SESSION['username']);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        echo "yes";
    } else {
        print_r($this->database->errorInfo());
    }
}
```

This is the output I get:

```
1111Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )
```

Database:

```
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `sandbox`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `inbox_unread`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inbox_unread` (
  `mail_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `body` text NOT NULL,
  `to` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `from` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`mail_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

'00000' apparently means successful, but it shouldn't be printing if it is successful.  Nothing is inserted to the database.  I'm sure it's a typo but I can't find it.

SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO inbox_unread (date, body, to, from) VALUES ('2013-01-04 23:40:58', 'test', 'will', 'will')
```

Comment: Did you try using a try/catch block to catch the real error instead of if/else? at the last part of your code?

Comment: Or just enable the normal error reporting with `PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING`.

Comment: try/catch fails completely.  Nothing happens when I use it.

Comment: Probably because your db connection is set to `PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT` (the default value). Try setting error reporting on like @mario suggested.

Comment: I changed the error reporting and it says I have an error in the SQL.  I tried manually putting it into the database and it still has an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a reserved word in your query:

```
   $stmt = $this->database->prepare("INSERT INTO 
    inbox_unread (date, body, to, `from`) VALUES (:date, :body, :to, :from)");
```

The Stackoverflow syntax highlighter actually made it obvious. With generic column names like that, it might be advisable to put them all in backticks perhaps.

Comment: yeah, I saw that once I added it on here.  Thanks.

Comment: +1 for catching the obvious lack of backticking a preserved word!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your values are all non-empty and valid (that you've already used `var_dump()` to make sure their values are gathered as expected)…

First, you might wanna use `$stmt->errorInfo()` instead of `$this->database->errorInfo()` since you're using a prepared statement.  [The documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php), in the final paragraph of the **"Return Values"** section reads:

> **`PDO::errorInfo()`** only retrieves error information for operations performed directly on the database handle. If you create a PDOStatement object through [**`PDO::prepare()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) or [**`PDO::query()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) and invoke an error on the statement handle, **`PDO::errorInfo()`** will not reflect the error from the statement handle. You must call [**`PDOStatement::errorInfo()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php) to return the error information for an operation performed on a particular statement handle.

Another thing you can do is, `var_dump` the `$stmt->execute()` call, so that you will have an exact idea about what it returns.

Lastly, [mario](https://stackoverflow.com/users/345031/mario) is right about turning the error reportings on. Take a look at [**PDO Errors and error handling**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) in documentation, if you like more detailed information about these.

Comment: +1, but I'm curious about why the execute fails. Everything is fine.

Comment: @Jeffrey I think your point might be the reason why. At the execution phase it's binding each parameter and it looks for the values of these references. So a string value itself will not have any reference, naturally.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line:

```
echo $stmt->bindParam(":date", date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
```

with these:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo $stmt->bindParam(":date", $date);
```

because `bindParam()` bind **variable by reference** not by value.

Comment: still not working.  I've checked all the params and they're all set.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not that experienced with the Binds, The manual for your binds go against what you have done.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Try removing your `echo` so your script looks like so:

```
   $stmt->bindParam(":date", date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
   $stmt->bindParam(":body", $body);
   $stmt->bindParam(":to", $to);
   $stmt->bindParam(":from", $_SESSION['username']);
```

Comment: The echos don't affect it.  They just output the return.

Comment: @WillHarrison Could you post a rough print out of your SQL Schema Data?

Comment: I've added it to the original post.